# C# Chart Series not found

Tags: c#, charts, series

Hey I have a problem with chart series

This is in the form.designer:

```
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea chartArea1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea();
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Legend legend1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Legend();
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series();
this.chart1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();

chartArea1.Name = "ChartArea1";
this.chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1);
legend1.Name = "Legend1";
this.chart1.Legends.Add(legend1);
this.chart1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(7, 17);
this.chart1.Name = "chart1";
series1.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
series1.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
series1.Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(128)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))));
series1.IsXValueIndexed = true;
series1.Legend = "Legend1";
series1.MarkerColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
series1.MarkerSize = 6;
series1.MarkerStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.MarkerStyle.Diamond;
series1.Name = "SeriesBatchPoint";
this.chart1.Series.Add(series1);
this.chart1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1141, 323);
this.chart1.TabIndex = 3;
this.chart1.Text = "chart1";
```

In the form I will make a point

```
chart1.Series["SeriesBatchPoint"].Points.AddXY(BatchCount, aTempWeightMesure);
```

I get this error:

> ArgumentException was unhandled
>
> Additional information: A chart element with the name 'SeriesBatchPoint' could not be found in the 'ChartAreaCollection'.

What am I do wrong?

Comment: Have you ever tried to access via the index on the series?

Comment: Are you sure of the order things happen? __After__ setting the `Name` you are able to access the series by that name just fine. Do use the debugger to have a look at the current series collection! I would also strongly advise to include the `using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;` namespace to make referencing thing easier.

Comment: Do you clear the series (instead of  clearing the points) at any time, before adding the point?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var series1 = chart1.Series.Add("SeriesBatchPoint");
series1.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
series1.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
// etc
```